# How to maintain Data through Data Management and Repository (DMR) recommended by oneM2M?

Tags: mbed, onem2m

We are implementing oneM2M standard in an open Source Embedded Operating system namely Mbed OS. We are using Nucleo Boards as our Application Dedicated Nodes and Middle Node. Since we need to implement DMR at MN and as we are using constrained device so the local DB is not an option. Is there any provision that how to implement DMR functionality as recommended by OneM2M. Current we are opting a remote DataBase (remote DMR) solution through HTTP get/post commands.

Answer (score 1):

How to store your resource depends on how the MN-CSE will be used.  I have built an implmentation of an MN-CSE using sqlite3.  If the number of resources you are storing is really small, it could be something even smaller, like stl containers from C++. oneM2M does not specify where you host you database, so a remote database is perfectly acceptable - my IN-CSE uses MongoDB which is remote as well.